# How can I identify my electric furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace, central-heating, electric-heat

I have a woodchuck wood and coal furnace which someone added an electric heater on top of.  The issue is I can't identify the electric heater, and it's in need of some servicing.  Anyone recognize what it might be?  I've tried looking all over for a model number.

So the reason I'm trying to find this out is I opened it up for the first time and found a corroded wire I want to fix but I don't know what it is.  Added a photo of the wire.

Electric addition is on top of the fuel burning blue part:
[image: Overview picture of entire furnace setup]

internals of the electric heater:
[image: internals of the electric heater]

[image: top of component box and cover]

[image: back and left]

[[image: top][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az9Ff.jpg)

[image: right side]
[image: back of cover plate]
[image: bad wire]

Comment: Either find the manufacturer's nameplate somewhere on the unit or replace it.

Comment: the most likely places for the model number are  on the inside surface of  the missing cover and next to the place at the back where the wires come in

Comment: Is there fine print or stamped numbers on the plate mounted beneath the metal shovel and above the door?

Comment: There could, annoyingly, be a label on the outside of the wiring cabinet, but that label be inaccessible because it's now on the bottom. Close up pics of the inside may help someone identify it.

Comment: @SteveWellens between the shovel and the door is the wood/coal furnace, (the indigo box)  this question is about the electric furnace, which is the galvanised box on top of it.

Comment: if there is a label on the underside it can probably be read if it can lit well enough and then a sharp photograph taken.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be constructed of generic parts. You'll be fine calling any competent HVAC technician.

Comment: Thanks but isn't this a DIY form?  Haha. You're right I might have to do that.

Comment: I may have mis-understood why you were asking for the model number

Comment: I want to do a tune up and servicing, but was looking for a model number so I can search the manual.

Comment: I found a bad wire that I want to fix. If these are generic parts can you help identify what it goes to so I can replace it?